# How to code an nth order Bezier curve

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to code an nth order bezier in javascript on canvas for a project. I want to be able to have the user press a button, in this case 'b', to select each end point and the control points. So far I am able to get the mouse coordinates on keypress and make quadratic and bezier curves using the built in functions. How would I go about making code for nth order?

Comment: Make an array, and store each line in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a Javascript implementation of nth order Bezier curves:

```js
// setup canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

ctx.fillText("INSTRUCTIONS: Press the 'b' key to add points to your curve. Press the 'c' key to clear all points and start over.", 20, 20);

// initialize points list
var plist = [];

// track mouse movements
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
});

// from: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#JavaScript
function binom(n, k) {
  var coeff = 1;
  for (var i = n - k + 1; i <= n; i++) coeff *= i;
  for (var i = 1; i <= k; i++) coeff /= i;
  return coeff;
}

// based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300
function bezier(t, plist) {
  var order = plist.length - 1;

  var y = 0;
  var x = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
    x = x + (binom(order, i) * Math.pow((1 - t), (order - i)) * Math.pow(t, i) * (plist[i].x));
    y = y + (binom(order, i) * Math.pow((1 - t), (order - i)) * Math.pow(t, i) * (plist[i].y));
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

// draw the Bezier curve
function draw(plist) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var accuracy = 0.01; //this'll give the 100 bezier segments
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(plist[0].x, plist[0].y);

  for (p in plist) {
    ctx.fillText(p, plist[p].x + 5, plist[p].y - 5);
    ctx.fillRect(plist[p].x - 5, plist[p].y - 5, 10, 10);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i += accuracy) {
    var p = bezier(i, plist);
    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// listen for keypress
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 66:
      // b key
      plist.push({
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
      });
      break;
    case 67:
      // c key
      plist = [];
      break;
  }
  draw(plist);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

This is based on [this implementation of cubic Bezier curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300/how-to-draw-bezier-curves-with-native-javascript-code-without-ctx-beziercurveto). In your application, it sounds like you'll want to populate the `points` array with user-defined points.

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question: what's the best way to add in the user defined points? I've been experimenting for the last day, but haven't come up with anything that works. What I want is for the user to press 'b' then it'll draw after each press, so you would press 'b' twice for line, 3 for quadratic, etc.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rphv/3jkt16Ly/3/) that might help. It adds a new point under the mouse pointer when the 'b' key is pressed, and clears the points list when you press 'c'. It also displays the (numbererd) points as they're added. To do this,  I refactored the drawing code into its own function `draw()`, moved `plist` into the global scope, and added a `mousemove` listener to keep track of the mouse position. Please consider upvoting the answer above if this helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote if I could, but it won't let me yet cause of rep. My account is very new

Comment: Not OP, but very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example for any number of points you want to add to make a bezier curve. Here points you will pass is an array of objects containing x and y values of points. [ { x: 1,y: 2 } , { x: 3,y: 4} ... ]

```
function factorial(n) {
    if(n<0)    
        return(-1); /*Wrong value*/      
    if(n==0)    
        return(1);  /*Terminating condition*/    
    else    
    {    
        return(n*factorial(n-1));        
    }
}

function nCr(n,r) {
    return( factorial(n) / ( factorial(r) * factorial(n-r) ) );
}

function BezierCurve(points) {
    let n=points.length;
    let curvepoints=[];
    for(let u=0; u <= 1 ; u += 0.0001 ){

        let p={x:0,y:0};

        for(let i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            let B=nCr(n-1,i)*Math.pow((1-u),(n-1)-i)*Math.pow(u,i);
            let px=points[i].x*B;
            let py=points[i].y*B;
            
            p.x+=px;
            p.y+=py;
            
        }

        curvepoints.push(p);
    }
    
    return curvepoints;
}
```